# Why in asp.net mvc enabling provider at ETW session throws error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, etw

This is the code part, where throws error

```
_traceEventSession = new TraceEventSession(SessionName, TraceEventSessionOptions.Create);
_traceEventSession.EnableProvider(
                ClrTraceEventParser.ProviderGuid,
                Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEventLevel.Verbose,
                (ulong)(ClrTraceEventParser.Keywords.Threading | ClrTraceEventParser.Keywords.Contention));
```

Error throws at calling `EnableProvider`

[image: Error stack]

In local environment all ok and I don't use KernelProvider, so I really can't understand why it's happen. Also I added all permissions for IIS_IUSRS in .NET Common Language Runtime provider section, but it didn't help at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to set the identity of the application pool to LocalService:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It really helped, but can there be some negative consequences after changing pool identity?

Comment: There is no negative impact, this will make your application pool have higher permissions so that you can use ETW. For more information about it, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/understanding-identities